# How can i learn reason of server load?

Tags: php, server-load

Nowadays i'm trying to change develop my system so i have been editing my files. But last 2-3 days my site gets more error(500) causing server load. How can i learn that reason of server load?

Comment: This is not a server load error I assume. It reminds `internal server error`. Do you have any htaccess file as most common reason?

Comment: If it's intermittent check your `tmp` folder

Comment: @YahyaE No i'm pretty sure it's about server load cause not only one file, all of files was unavailable. And there was ten lines whics is like that:
"PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1572864) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes)"

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 Yes it's intermittent but i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You may have a query that is maxing the `tmp` folder.. are you using `mysql`?  .. and paste the code on the page that gives the error

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have run out of allocatable PHP memory.

```
PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1572864) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes)
```

Either you have done something very odd to your code or what you are doing requires more memory to run properly.

Try this:

Edit your php.ini and change this parameter

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

yours may be set to 128Meg as thats the default, if it is try changing it to

```
memory_limit = 256M
```